# Is there an iOS equivalent to android's audiotrack?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, audio, audio-streaming

I have an algorithm working on android for playing some synthesized audio. I do this using the audiotrack API (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html). This allows me to effectively push the byte array straight to the audio stream... Meaning as long as I can keep this data coming, it won't glitch or otherwise become inaccurate.

Is there an equivalent on iOS?

I can't seem to find anything that will let me push an array containing audio data directly to the audio stream. I got my hopes up with Audiograph - but can't see how to do it using that... and that is, apparently the lowest level api. I wonder if perhaps using something related to audio streaming would make sense?

Effectively all I want to do is draw a graph, and have the device play it.

Any ideas appreciated!

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can use Audio ToolBox framework to do that. It containt several classes to maintain audio. This is some references for you.

[Audio Session](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007915) and [Audio File Stream Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006162)

hope it will help you.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for some sort of streaming audio solution? Perhaps Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer project might be of help?

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

**Edit:** AudioStreamer makes use of the AudioToolbox as mentioned by andikurnia.